# No converter found capable of converting from type org.bson.types.ObjectId to type int

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring data and mongodb to get all `Products` using this function:

```
@Repository
public class ProductDao  {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;
    public List<Product> getAll() {
            return mongoOperations.findAll(Product.class);
        }
}
```

**My product class:**

```
@Document(collection = Product.COLLECTION_NAME)
public class Product implements Serializable {

    public Product() {
    }

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "product";

    @Id
    private String _id;
    private String name;
    private DateTime date_time;
    private int fk_properties;
    private List<Integer> fk_parts;
}
```

**Error:**

```
    org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: 
No converter found capable of converting from type org.bson.types.ObjectId to type int
```

How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I do have `spring-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar`  in lib folder which suppose to include required converter.

**UPDATE 2:**
Document

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5449567cdf97f277c50d1ce2"), 
    "name" : "2014 ISF", 
    "auction_start" : ISODate("2014-12-08T12:00:00.000+0200"), 
    "auction_end" : ISODate("2014-12-08T14:00:00.000+0200"), 
    "listed" : "F", 
    "fk_product_property" : ObjectId("5229567cdf97f277c50d1ce2"), 
    "fk_parts" : [
        ObjectId("5339567cdf97f277c50d1ce2"), 
        ObjectId("5349567cdf97f277c50d1ce2")
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have documents in the product collection whose id type is integer? `db.product.find({"_id" : {$type : 16}})`

Comment: It returns nothing while executing `db.product.find({"_id" : {$type : 16}})` in command line...

Comment: Can you post your sample document, it will help us determine datatype mismatch issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to implicitly convert an ObjectId to an Integer:

`private List<Integer> fk_parts;`

should be:

`private List<ObjectId> fk_parts;`

Also note that `private int fk_properties;` is mapped to nothing. If you want it to map to `fk_product_property` as I suspect, it should be:

`private ObjectId fk_product_property`

or

`@Field("fk_product_property") private ObjectId fk_properties;`

In any case that field also should be mapped to `ObjectId` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your "foreign key" should be annotated with [@DbRef](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/DBRef.html)